# Separating an array into 5 different arrays depending on an argument

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I am writing a program where I need to generate 100 random grades and then categorize them based on their value. 100-90 in one, 89 to 70 in another; 69-50; 49-20; 19 to 0.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    grades[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;  
}
```

I created a loop that stores randomly generated numbers into a given array, grades[100], and want to categorize them into five more arrays based on the information on the given above. I tried making another loop with five more nested loops set with an if condition, for the grades, and used size of - 1 the array to store if, but realized it bugged out because I was forced to define the arrays I was storing it in. Therefore, doing sizeof arrayEX[100] would always return 100 and I continuously stored the value into the same index (99).

How can I separate and store an array properly into another array, especially since I cannot define the array since I don't know how many values will be going into it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use STL? For example [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) would do a great job against this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    grades[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;  
}

std::vector<int> gradeA, gradeB, gradeC, gradeD, gradeE;
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    if (grades[i]>=90)
        gradeA.push_back(grades[i]);
    else if (grades[i]>=70)
        gradeB.push_back(grades[i]);
    else if (grades[i]>=50)
        gradeC.push_back(grades[i]);
    else if (grades[i]>=20)
        gradeD.push_back(grades[i]);
    else
        gradeE.push_back(grades[i]);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! My professor never taught me vector so I never used it, I guess its better than new (?) since it seems to not work as well in c9 as my ide (idk why)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> gradeBuckets(5);
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    int grade = rand() % 100 + 1;

    if (grade < 20) {
        gradeBuckets[0].push_back(grade);
    } else if(grade < 50) {
        gradeBuckets[1].push_back(grade);
    } else if ...
```