# Condensing for 5 for-loops that display an array into 1?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, coding-style

Is there a way to condense five for-loops into one and have them display different variables and letters for each? Currently, I have one loop with five other loops and if/else to keep it condense, but this seems redundant and defeats the very purpose of making the loop.

So I decided to post the whole source code so people can understand what I am trying to get at more. This is a program that creates 100 random grades everytime it runs and I have to sort them, then display them. I am aware I could do 5 for loops, but I want to write code that is more condensed and efficient.

The hard part is writing a loop that can display 5 arrays consistently even though the size of the array changes every run.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    int grades[100];
    int sizeA=0, sizeB=0, sizeC=0, sizeD=0, sizeF=0;
    std::vector<int> gradeA, gradeB, gradeC, gradeD, gradeF;

    srand(time(NULL));

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        grades[i] = rand() % 100 + 1;  
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
        if (grades[i] < 100 || grades[i] > 0){
            if (grades[i]>=90)
                gradeA.push_back(grades[i]);
            else if (grades[i]>=70)
                gradeB.push_back(grades[i]);
            else if (grades[i]>=50)
                gradeC.push_back(grades[i]);
            else if (grades[i]>=20)
                gradeD.push_back(grades[i]);
            else if (grades[i])
                gradeF.push_back(grades[i]);
        } else {
            cout << "uhh.. ";
            return(0);
        }
    }

    sizeA = gradeA.size();
    sizeB = gradeB.size();
    sizeC = gradeC.size();
    sizeD = gradeD.size();
    sizeF = gradeF.size();


    /**toggle ? showgrades(gradeA, size) : (int?)null;**/

}
```

Comment: So you mean that you don't actually need the outer loop, since every body of the if statements will be executed only once? 5 if statements and 5 iterations, 1 iteration for 1 if statement?

Comment: @gsamaras I did that going in with the mindset of condensing how many couts I have, but then it got out of hand. 5 for loops seems too messy and takes too much space, as does this, which is why I am asking how others would condense it.

Comment: What are all these variables? And what data structure are you using? It seems like you are using some sort of array-like container, while it appears you'd want a `map` or something along those lines

Comment: maybe create a struct that contains grades and class'(as in school class) name. so you can create an array of that struct and simply loop over it without those if checks for printing name.

Comment: This looks like a follow-up question of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48455907/5958455),

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about using a function to do the looping and call it with the required information

```
void printGrades(const std::vector<int>& grades, char level) {
  cout << num << " " << level << " students: ";
  for(int i = 0; i < grades.size(); i++){
    cout << grades[i] << " ";
  cout << endl;
}
```

So when you want to print them all:

```
printGrades(gradeA, 'A');
printGrades(gradeB, 'B');
printGrades(gradeC, 'C');
printGrades(gradeD, 'D');
printGrades(gradeF, 'F');
```

Comment: The follow-on, is to compact `gradeA`, `gradeB` etc into a `std::array<std::vector<int>,GradeCount>`.  At that point you don't need an independent  `sizeA` variable, and with a `static const std::array<char,GradeCount> levels = {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'};`, you can call `printGrades` in a loop: `for (int i=0; i < GradeCount; i++) { printGrades(grades[i], levels[i]);}`

Comment: I don't know if the brackets before grades was intentional or not in the function header, but doing that gives the following error: cpp:5:24: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘grades’ void printGrades(int[] grades, int num, char level) {

Comment: @Vincent d'oh! you're right, they go after... I'll edit

Comment: @vu1p3n0x The only issue now is, because it used a vector method to organize 1 array into 5 separate arrays, it wont convert into an int, thus throwing: `  cpp:48:35: error: cannot convert ‘std::vector<int>’ to ‘int*’ for argument ‘1’ to ‘void printGrades(int*, int, char)’
     printGrades(gradeA, sizeA, 'A'); cout << endl; ` I posted the whole source code above for you to look at.

Comment: @Vincent updated, I didn't see that you edited the question to provide the type of the grades.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x Thank you so much. Sorry I had to rely on you, other questions answered on stack didn't seem to work for me. :) I understand how to fix these in the future now

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would create a class Student, and then a 2D array, where every row would represent the student's category, and the number of columns of a row, the number of students.

That could be represented as a fixed-sized array of size 5, where every cell would be a `std::vector` of `class Student`.

Minimal working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Student {
public:
    Student(int grade, char category) : grade(grade), category(category) {}
    int getGrade(void) { return grade; }
    char getCategory(void) { return category; }
private:
    int grade;     // 0, ..., 20
    char category; // A, ..., F
};

int main(void) {
    vector<class Student> std[5]; // cell 0 is for A students, ..., cel 4 is for F students
    std[0].push_back({20, 'A'}); std[0].push_back({19, 'A'});
    std[1].push_back({15, 'B'});
    std[2].push_back({17, 'C'}); std[2].push_back({17, 'C'});
    std[3].push_back({14, 'D'});
    std[4].push_back({15, 'F'});

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        if(std[i].size()) {
            cout << std[i].size() << " " << std[i][0].getCategory() << " students: ";
            for (auto& student : std[i]) {
                cout << student.getGrade() << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }     
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
2 A students: 20 19 
1 B students: 15 
2 C students: 17 17 
1 D students: 14 
1 F students: 15
```

---

Appendix:

I understand that you want to make the code compact, but this:

```
for(int a = 0; a < sizeA; a++){
    cout << gradeA[a] << " ";
} aS = 1; bS = 0; cout << endl;
```

is *not* cool, since it's not readable for the reader. I suggest you to change it to:

```
for(int a = 0; a < sizeA; a++){
    cout << gradeA[a] << " ";
}
aS = 1;
bS = 0;
cout << endl;
```

since a reader expects to see no code after the closing curly bracket. That's a general statement.

Comment: I agree with the appendix for real code, but for an SO example, the compaction is rather useful.